# How to wrap text in the Label without specifying height of the element

Tags: eclipse-rap

Problem is that I can't set the height of the Label. For a long text my Label should have height for 2 rows, with a short text only  1 row.
There is code example:

```java
public MyComposite(Composite parent) {
    super(parent, SWT.NONE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    description = new Label(this, SWT.WRAP);
    description.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    description.setText("Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo" + 
    "oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo" + 
    "ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable wrapping text in a GridLayout, you have to set the 3rd parameter of the GridData (`grabExcessHorizontalSpace`) to `true`. Also make sure that the parent composite's size is defined by its layoutData, otherwise it will be expanded by the Label. The following snippet has the label text wrapped:

```
Shell shell = new Shell( parentShell );
shell.setSize( 400, 300 );
shell.setLayout( new GridLayout(1, false) );
Label description = new Label(shell, SWT.WRAP);
description.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
description.setText("Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo" +
    "oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo" +
    "ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text");
shell.open();
```

Also note that wrapping is implemented as word-wrap, a very long sequence of non-whitespace characters won't be split into lines.

Comment: Thanks! And i found that a very long sequence of non-whitespace characters can be splitted by read-only Text widget.